# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. How could I solve this problem?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to do the 'Update products' function by using NodeJS and MongoDB but I am struggling with an error like this: "***UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined***". And below is the source of code to do this function. I truly hope some of you can tell me where I am wrong and give me a solution. Thank you in advance!

```
<button type="submit" class="btn1 success"><a href="/update-products?id={{_id}} " style="text-decoration: none">Update</a></button>
// This form below is in the update-products.hbs.
<form action="/do-update-products" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{model._id}}">
       <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ model.name }}" placeholder="Name for the product.." />
       <input type="text" name="price" value="{{ model.price }}" placeholder="Price.." />
       <input type="text" name="image" value="{{ model.image }}" placeholder="Link for the image.." />
       <input type="text" name="brand" value="{{ model.brand }}" placeholder="Brand.." />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


router.get('/update-products', async function(req, res, next) {
    const id = req.params.id;
    var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
    let client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
    let dbo = client.db("HomeFitness");
    const result = await dbo.collection("products").findOne({ _id: ObjectID(id) });
    res.render("update-products", { model: result });
});

// Do update product
router.post("/do-update-products", async(req, res) => {
    let newData = {
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
        image: req.body.image,
        brand: req.body.brand
    };
    var id = req.body.id;
    let client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    let dbo = client.db("HomeFitness");
    var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
    await dbo
        .collection("products")
        .updateOne({ _id: ObjectID(id) }, { $set: newData });
    res.redirect("/statistics-products");
});
```

Comment: can you make sure if you are getting values under `req.body`?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP response parsing is not correctly configured to parse form-data responses. This problem manifests itself as the `body` property of the request (`req`) being undefined and possibly not present. Have you configured something like [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)?

```js
...
let newData = {
  // `req.body` is undefined, so you cannot access `req.body.name`
  name: req.body.name, // TypeError!
  price: req.body.price,
  image: req.body.image,
...
```

Comment: No, that would not work, and would cause further issues. As I said in my answer, the input HTTP body is form-data, not JSON, and cannot be parsed by a JSON parser.

Comment: I see what you mean, in that case `JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData))` can solve this problem

Comment: So I need to include body-parser like this "var bodyParser = require("body-parser");"?

Comment: @HuyQuang Yes, you would need to install and include body-parser using a statement like that, then add body parsing to your app with a snippet like `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())`.

Comment: @jatinderbhola Please stop posting links to this Medium blog post, and please stop posting untested solutions. Your 2nd solution would also not work, `formData` is not defined.

Comment: @luawtf so far, I have not committed 100% solution. Just trying to understand and provide the points which may be causing the problem. links are just for reference and more understanding. anyway...

Comment: Calm down, guys. I'm a newbie so this stuff must be tough for me. Anyway, I truly appreciate your help.